# Is test suite scheduling possible in Junit?

Tags: java, testing, junit, automation, testng

I'm using Junit to automate my current web application. I want to schedule Junit test suite and email the result report to various people, is it possible in Junit?  If not is there any plugin available to do so?
If I need to migrate it to TestNG how can we do it?

Comment: JUnit is a toolset for creating tests. To run these tests automatically you need some kind of test server e.g. Jenkins, GitLab CI, ...

Answer (score 1):

Scheduling unit test jobs and emailing test results are not the concern of a unit test framework such as JUnit or TestNG.

This kind of functionality is within the problem domain of Continuous Integration (CI) software, such as Jenkins, Travis, CircleCI, and so on.

For example Jenkins will run a Java project's unit tests (using your chosen unit test framework) as part of a regular build.  You can trigger build jobs on checkin to your source control repository, or on a regular schedule.  Jenkins also has a plugin for sending email notifications when a build job completes.

References:

- [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)
- [Comparison of Continuous Integration Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_continuous_integration_software)

Alternatively, you could simply run builds out of cron jobs and use cron's builtin ability to send an email containing the job's output.